# Java program factorials

Tags: java

Here's how it's written in the book:

"The value `e^x` can be approximated by the following sum:

> 1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+...+x^n/n!

Write a program that takes a value x as input and outputs this sum for n taken to be each of the values 1 to 10, 50, and 100. Your program should repeat the calculation for new values of x until the user says she or he is through. The expression n! is called the factorial of n and is defined as

> n! = 1*2*3*...*n

Use variables of type double to store the factorials (or arrange your calculation to avoid any direct calculation of factorials); otherwise, you are likely to produce integer overflow, that is, integers larger than Java allows."

I don't have any coding problems (not yet at least), my problem is I don't know what it's asking me to do. I get the factorial part `(ex. 3i = 1*2*3)` but I am just not sure what else it is asking. I have the user input a value for "x" but where does the "n" come from?

"The value `e^x` can be approximated by the following sum:

> 1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+...+x^n/n!

" I don't know what this is saying or asking for.

I put together this for loop for the 1-10, 50, 100 part and I don't know if that even makes sense without understanding the rest, but here it is:

```
for (counter = 1 ; counter <= 100 ;counter++)
{
    //System.out.print("Enter value for x: ");
    //x = keyIn.nextDouble();
    if (counter >= 1 && counter <= 10)
    { 
        if (counter == 1)
            System.out.println("Iterations 1-10: ");
        System.out.println("test to see if 10 show up");
    }
    else if (counter == 50)
    { 
        System.out.println("Iteration 50: ");
    }
    else if (counter == 100)
    { 
        System.out.println("Iteration 100: ");
    }
}
```

I haven't been in algebra in about two years so some of this stuff is throwing me off a bit. Please help with whatever you can, thanks.

Comment: It's asking for you to compute `e^x` for some value of `x` using the Taylor series of the exponential function. `e^x` is *approximately* equal to `1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+...+x^n/n!` for some large value of `n`.

Comment: yes @Blender  is correct n means some large number. It can be user input or any fix number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying that `e^x` can be approximated through a Taylor Series: `Sum(i:0:n)`(x<sup>i</sup>/fact(i))
So, we have:

```
double ex_taylor_series(double x, int n)
{
     double value;

     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
         value += Math.pow(x, i)/(factorial(i));
     }

     return value;
}

private int factorial (int num)
{
      int value = 1;

      for(int i = num; i > 1; i--)
      {
           value *= i;
      }

      return value;
}
```

In your case, you would simply feed different values of n, 10, 50 and 100, to `ex_taylor_series`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I just need one more bit of clarification, why does it have an "e" and an "n" variable. That's the part that tripped me up, I have user input "x" but then there are "n" and "e" floating around in the formula and I wasn't sure what to code those values as. Also, my book has never gone over "pow()" method at all.

Comment: Read up on [Taylor Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).  Basically, you can approximate a function through the summation.  In your case, we're approximating `e^x`, but at varying levels of approximation: 10, 50 and 100 iterations.  Increasing the number of iterations increases the accuracy of the approximation...Since you're new, you should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Good luck.

Comment: Welp, I finished it and it runs as it should. I figured out what the formula was saying and then used two code lines a piece for the power raising and factorial part, and that did the trick! Thank you, Steve and others.